# duplicity restore failed - urgent help please

Tags: duplicity

Duplicity restore failed 
After my fresh ubuntu 16.04LTS install, when i tried to restore from my duplicity back from my external usb, it fails with the message:

Failed to read /tmp/duplicity-QOZBhY-tempdir/mktemp-WsEwV2-1: (, error('Error -3 while decompressing: invalid stored block lengths',), )

I've the drive filled with backups from a year ago. Is there a way to get my system restored from this??

Comment: Had same issue, I created a directory in ( `~/home`) the new install and restored to that location and copied my needed files over. Only thing is that its good for `~/home` only. Other configuration will have to be re-configured

Comment: Hi Thanks. Can you give a little more clarification on this? What directory should i create in home directory and what should i copy? I f i can retrieve stuff like settings and other programs I've installed before the OS reinstall, I'll be more than happy.

Comment: Create a folder of any name in `~/home` or `~/home/$USERNAME`, then direct  it to restore there, but again your won't be able to immediately use your installed app as those will have to be done again manually

Comment: Right now, when i ppint the source backup folder to my external usb, after reading it for a while, I get the error msg. If i point the restore folder to a new folder, will this error still not show up as its not able to read the backup source file?

Comment: Please try it first so we know for sure!

Comment: I tried. but it doesn't even go to the next step where it asks you where to restore. First step is to point to the backup folder in my usb drive and it reads it for a while and throws this error msg. Is there a way to go back to the last good backup and restore what i can? All i need is the ubuntu desktop setup and programs the way i had it. Personal data such as pictures etc i've backed up separately

Comment: Same issue here, I'm going to try to manually extract duplicity archives. Found this link that describes how to do it:
[https://serverfault.com/questions/89355/extract-duplicity-difftar-files-manually](https://serverfault.com/questions/89355/extract-duplicity-difftar-files-manually)